# Checking username availability - Handling of AJAX requests (Google App Engine)

Tags: python, ajax, google-app-engine, memcached, google-cloud-datastore

I want to add the 'check username available' functionality on my signup page using AJAX. I have few doubts about the way I should implement it.

1. With which event should I register my AJAX requests? We can send the
   requests when user focus out of the 'username' input field (blur
   event) or as he types (keyup event). Which provides better user
   experience?
2. On the server side,  a simple way of dealing with requests would be
   to query my main 'Accounts' database. But this could lead to a lot
   of request hitting my database(even more if we POST using the keyup
   event). Should I maintain a separate model for registered usernames
   only and use that to get better results?
3. Is it possible to use Memcache in this case? Initializing cache with
   every username as key and updating it as we register users and use a
   random key to check if cache is actually initialized or pass the
   queries directly to db.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answers -

1. Do the check on blur.  If you do it on key up, you will be hammering your server with unnecessary queries, annoying the user who is not yet done typing, and likely lag the typing anyway.
2. If your Account entity is very large, you may want to create a separate AccountName entity, and create a matching such entity whenever you create a real Account (but this is probably an unnecessary optimization).  When you create the Account (or AccountName), be sure to assign id=name when you create it. Then you can do an AccountName.get_by_id(name) to quickly see if the AccountName has already been assigned, and it will automatically pull it from memcache if it has been recently dealt with.
3. By default, GAE NDB will automatically populate memcache for you when you put or get entities.  If you follow my advice in step 2, things will be very fast and you won't have to mess around with pre-populating memcache.

If you are concerned about 2 people simultaneously requesting the same user name, put your create method in a transaction:

```
@classmethod
@ndb.transactional()
def create_account(cls, name, other_params):
    acct = Account.get_by_id(name)
    if not acct:
        acct = Account(id=name, other param assigns)
        acct.put()
```

Comment: Thanks! I switched to the blur event since keyup event is a bit of overkill for signup. Also, +1 for giving heads-up to use get_by_id and create_account as a classmethod. Though, I still populate my memcache just as an extra layer since I don't know how Google's auto caching works.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend the blur event of the username field, combined with some sort of inline error/warning display.

I would also suggest maintaining a memcache of registered usernames, to reduce DB hits and improve user experience - although probably not populate this with a warm-up, but instead only when requests are made.  This is sometimes called a "Repository" pattern.

BUT, you can only populate the cache with USED usernames - you should not store the "available" usernames here (or if you do, use a much lower timeout).

You should always check directly against the DB/Datastore when actually performing the registration. And ideally in some sort of transactional method so that you don't have race conditions with multiple people registering.

BUT, all of this work is dependant on several things, including how busy your app is and what data storage tech you are using!

Comment: I am using App Engine Datastore (it's mentioned in question tags but, I will edit and add that in question). How should we deal with stale cache in this case. If 2 users try to register with same username and one gets registered and other is rejected by db(though our cache query said username is available)? Is this an acceptable quirk of using memcache?

Comment: As mentioned, I would recommend you ONLY cache "used" usernames. Which would mean the race condition would be rare. And if you do the actual create in a transactional block, then you will not allow 2 users to be created with the same name.